# Linear Programming - variable that equals the sign of an expression

Tags: linear-programming, divide-by-zero

I am trying to write a linear program and need a variable z that equals the sign of x-c, where x is another variable, and c is a constant.

I considered `z = (x-c)/|x-c|`. Unfortunately, if x=c, then this creates division by 0.

I cannot use z=x-c, because I don't want to weight it by the magnitude of the difference between x and c.

Does anyone know of a good way to express z so that it is the sign of x-c?

Thank you for any help and suggestions!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming (coding).

Comment: This is not linear programming anymore, because the sign function is non-linear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't model `z = sign(x-c)` exactly with a linear program (because the constraints in an LP are restricted to linear combinations of variables).

However, you can model `sign` if you are willing to convert your linear program into a mixed integer program, you can model this with the following two constraints:

```
 L*b <= x - c <= U*(1-b)
 z = 1 - 2*b
```

Where `b` is a binary variable, and `L` and `U` are lower and upper bounds on the quantity `x-c`. If `b = 0`, we have `0 <= x - c <= U` and `z = 1`.  If `b = 1`, we have `L <= x - c <= 0` and `z = 1 - 2*1 = -1`.

You can use a solver like [Gurobi](http://gurobi.com) to solve mixed integer programs.

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone's advice and comments! I appreciate it.  The answer by codehippo about using L, U, and b is just what I was looking for!  I have one follow-up question.  Is there a way to include the possibility that z=0, so x=c?  With what we have, if z=0, then b=1/2, and L/2 <= x-c <= U/2.  That last expression could be true even when x is not equal to c.

Comment: @user3482751 if x=c, you have L*b <= 0 <= U*(1-b). This constraint is satisfied for both b = 0 (0 <= 0 <= U) and b = 1 (L <= 0 <= 0). Meaning that when x=c, z could be either -1 or 1. Do you need to be able to distinguish when x=c?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @codehippo! Yes, I need to be able to distinguish when x=c. In my "game", x>c gives person x a point, x<c gives person c a point, and x=c gives neither person a point.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: @user3482751 This approach won't allow you to exactly determine if x==c. The best you can do is modify the above so that it can distinguish abs(x - c) < epsilon for some small epsilons say 1e-6.

Comment: @codehippo Can we make it chose only -1  if x==c? currently z can be either 1 or -1.

Comment: This is simply a bad and wrong answer.  Using two binary variables you can do X+M×s-M×t==0 and z+s+t==1 where z, s and t are binary variables representing zero, negative or positive.  How this got accepted is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

For k » 1 this is a smooth approximation of the sign function:

[image]

Also

[image]

when ε → 0

These two approximations haven't the division by 0 issue but now you must tune a parameter.

---

In some languages (e.g. C++ / C) you can simply write something like this:

```
double sgn(double x)
{
  return (x > 0.0) - (x < 0.0);
}
```

Anyway consider that many environments / languages already have a sign function, e.g.

- [Sign[x]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html) in Mathematica
- [sign(x)](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) in Matlab
- [Math.signum(x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in Java
- [sign(1, x)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIGN.html) in Fortran
- [sign(x)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sign.html) in R

Pay close attention to what happens when x is equal to 0 (e.g. the Fortran function will return 1, with other languages you'll get 0).

Comment: division by zero is certainly an issue. But I think the bigger issue is that he can't use the above nonlinear approximations in a linear program.

Comment: Well, you're right. I'll keep the answer if anyone seeks more details about sign function.

Answer (score 0):

`x-c+M×s-N×t==0` and `z+s+t==1` with `z,s,t` being Booleans representing zero, negative or positive and `M` and `N` representing slack variables.  It's very straight forward.  The other answers saying it's not possible are wrong.  `M×s` and `N×t` are easily linearized via the Fortet inequalities.  For this reason, the accepted answer is subpar and misleading.