# Linear Programming: Depict logical expression in a boolean variable

Tags: linear-programming

I have a mixed integer linear program (MIP or MILP).
In the end I want a boolean variable im my linear program, that has the following properties.

I have two variables:

```
boolean b.
real x, with x being 0 or larger.
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
b == false if x == 0.
b == true if  x >  0.
```

I found a way to depict if x is in specific range (e.g. between 2 and 3) via:

```
2*b <= x
x   <= 3*b
```

The problem with the above testing formula is, that b will be true if x is in the given range and false if outside that range.

Does  anybody know a way to set a boolean variable to false if x == 0 and to true if x is larger than 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `U` is an upper bound of `x` then

```
if x > 0 ==> b == 1
```

can be made as

```
x <= U*b
```

The second part (`x == 0 => b == 0`) needs to be modified to

```
x < epsilon ==> b == 0
```

which can be made as

```
b <= 1 + x - epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is a small number. Other than good practice this is necessary, because solvers do not work in rational arithmetic ([although there are some research efforts to make them do so](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637707000211)), but with certain precision thresholds, and therefore quantities such as `10e-12` are treated as zero.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the signum function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function take the absolute value and negate it. Since you didn't name a specific programming language I keep it general.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use such a function in linear programming or linear optimization.

Comment: Sure you are right, but can you model sign by following this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788264/linear-programming-variable-that-equals-the-sign-of-an-expression